# obter dados com PHP + codeigniter ao clicar em um botao

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud

Boa tarde galera segue uma duvida

Possuo uma lista conforme abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar em histórico  sou direcionado para esta pagina:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Nesta pagina esta sendo exibido todos os comentários feitos para o cliente superar

Ao clicar em novo comentário sou direcionado para esta pagina:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vejam que na pagina para adicionar um novo comentário o campo cliente deve ser preenchido.

O que eu gostaria de saber é como posso fazer para que este campo seja preenchido automaticamente com o cliente, por exemplo se estamos visualizando o histórico de comentários do cliente superar, ao clicar em novo comentário o campo cliente seja preenchido com o cliente superar.

Comment: Acho que essa tag "passagem-por-referência" está equivocada. Não tem haver com isso sua dúvida. Passagem por referência se aplica a outro contexto.

Comment: nem a tag "crud"

Comment: Isso está vago. De que forma os dados desse cliente estão sendo carregados para a `VIEW`? Como esse botão está carregando a outra página? Com um `FORM`? Com `Ajax`? Por link?

Answer (score 3):

No seu Controller, provavelmente tem algum código assim:

```
public function novoComentario() {
    $this->load->view('novo_comentario');
}
```

O que você precisa fazer é receber o código do cliente através da URL(GET), procurar esse cliente no banco de dados, e carregar a View passando essa informação. Fica mais ou menos assim:

```
public function novoComentario($id) {
    $this->load->model("ClienteModel");

    // implemente buscarPorCodigo em ClienteModel
    $nome = $this->ClienteModel->buscarPorCodigo($id)->nome;

    $data = ["nome_cliente" => $nome];

    $this->load->view('novo_comentario', $data);
}
```

Na sua View

```
<input type="text" value="<?= $nome_cliente ?>" >
```

O link do botão "Histórico" na View "Lista de Clientes" precisa ficar assim:

```
http://localhost/seusite/index.php/comentarios/novoComentario/1032
```